# How to set id in angular2 dynamically

Tags: angular

Is there anyway we can set id conditionally in angular2. Lets say I have a component template.

```html
<span id="setTextId()">
```

I want to set my id return by this setTextId() function how can i do that?

Comment: Instead of dynamically created id, why not just use a class?

Comment: Put this <span [id]="setTextId()">text</span> where setTextId return a name of id, or put a variable

Answer (score 3):

```
span [id]="setTextId()"
```

In Component the method will be

```
id : number = 0;

setTextId(){
  this.id++
}
```