# How do I set id using (#) dynamically in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on an angular 6 application which uses dynamic components. I am using `@ViewChild('<id>', { read: ViewContainerRef }) <id>;` in order to refer to the `divs` I would populate with dynamic components. The `ViewContainerRef` looks for a `#` tag with an id to identify which item it refers to in the template.

I have created an accordion within which I want to dynamically add a specific reusable component, which I have been doing throughout the rest of the application by the process mentioned above. However, since there are many tabs in an accordion I want to add a loop using `*ngFor` that would do the job for me, where I set the `#id` using a value specified in the loop. I implemented the following template:

```
<app-create-feature-modal></app-create-feature-modal>
<app-button description="{{ 'pages[knowledge_base][buttons][accordion_add]' | translate }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md accordion-button" (callFunction)="add()"></app-button>
<div class="acc">
  <div *ngFor="let item of meta; let i = index">
    <button class="accordion" (click)="toggle(i)">{{item.name}}</button>
    <div class="{{'panel panel-'+ i}}">
      <div #{{item.value}}></div>   <!--here-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, on running the application, the `id` is not properly set and on inspecting the console I see that the reference to `@ViewChild` is undefined, and even within the html there are no id's defined, just plain divs.

I cannot use `id="{{item.value}}"` because the `ViewContainerRef` does not recognize it, which is why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550863/how-to-set-id-in-angular2-dynamically) solution would not work for me.

Is there any possible way I can achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220608/how-do-you-dynamically-change-the-id-of-an-element-in-angular this may help

Comment: Hi, @RaviRajput, I can't use the `id="{{item.value}}"` because then the `ViewContainerRef` doesn't recognize it. It needs to be in the `#id` syntax

Comment: You can get ref to your element after view is initialized with dynamic id's
in 
`ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('1'));
}`

Comment: Use https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren

Comment: # reference when used in `*ngFor`  points to different  element in each iteration , so no need to auto generate the # reference . `<div #{{item.value}}></div>` this usage is wrong and is not the right way to use template reference variable

Comment: @meh you can just use `<div #something></div>` and then access the elements using `@ViewChildren('something') somethingElemnts: QueryList<ElementRef>;`

Comment: @JoelJoseph but what if I have a hundred <div #some_id></div> elements, in that case it might not be feasable to write every single div manually

Comment: @meh no need to write 100 of them manually `@ViewChildren('something') somethingElemnts: QueryList<ElementRef>;` this gives the list of all the `<div #something></div>` elements generated using `*ngFor`

Comment: @mehvariable `somethingElemnts` will have all the elements that are using the `#something` template reference variable

Comment: @JoelJoseph could you please explain with a small stackblitz or plunkr example? I feel you may be talking about where `#something` is the same for all elements. For me all these elements would have a different tag eg. `#something` `#someother` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `[attr.id]="item.value"`.

```html
<div [attr.id]="item.value"></div>
```

Comment: the question is related to "template reference variable", not about id attribute. And yes, in the comments indicate to "reach" it you need use ViewChildren is it was necessary from .ts. Generally it's not necessary because you pass to the function as argument